# query regarding cloud file storage services- can i append data to an existing file

Tags: amazon-s3, rackspace

I am working to create an application where some files will be stored in Amazon S3/Rackspace Cloud Files/other similar cloud file storage providers.

There are a couple of scenarios where it would be easier for me, if I could append data to an existing file... Is this possible? Or do I have to download the file from Amazon S3, then append data to it, and finally upload the modified file back to Amazon S3?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to append anything to existing files in S3.
You will have to download it and upload it again after modifying.

If you wish though, you can always upload the new data with a tag (a timestamp or a counter), e.g. file_201201011344. So when reading files, you get all files mactching your pattern and append them on the client side.